# Display wp author meta url without 'http'

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the WP function: `get_the_author_meta('user_url');`

When I echo that to the browser it automatically prepends 'http://' to the URL. How can I avoid this, so that my URLs show exactly as they are entered on the user settings page.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$author_url = get_the_author_meta('user_url'); // e.g. http://www.example.com
$to_remove = array( 'http://', 'https://' );
foreach ( $to_remove as $item ) {
    $author_url = str_replace($item, '', $author_url); // to: www.example.com
}
echo $author_url; // now it will not have the http:// part you wish to avoid.
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Just one minor syntax error in your code: first instance of the variable `author_url` needs the `$` in front of it.

Comment: I need some favor here, why don't we trim http when saving the data into mysql. Can anyone suggest me from which action file the wp is saving the data?

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` is probably the most efficient way of doing this.

```
$author_url = str_replace(array( 'http://', 'https://' ), '', get_the_author_meta('user_url'));
```

---

Other URL modification techniques.

- For more complicated string replacements which match you could look at using `preg_replace` .
- There is a function called `http-build-url()` which is included in the `php_http.dll` extension which might be more suitable for some use cases.